# oracle text ctxrule - MATCHES: special word work and not work?

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

I use CTXRULE to classify some text, but AB&B work and AT&T not work. Please support me on this:

Here is my search text

```
SQL> select text from test_lexer_special;

TEXT
--------------------
AB&B
{AT&T}
AT&T

SQL>
```

How I create index

```
SQL> EXEC CTX_DDL.CREATE_INDEX_SET('test_ctxrule_1');    
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE ('testmy_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');    
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE ('testmy_lexer', 'PRINTJOINS', '&');    
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> CREATE INDEX test_ctxrule_index1 ON test_lexer_special (text)
  2  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXRULE  
  3  PARAMETERS ('INDEX SET test_ctxrule_1 LEXER testmy_lexer STOPLIST CTXSYS.EMPTY_STOPLIST');

Index created.

SQL>
```

This works

```
SQL> SELECT *  FROM    test_lexer_special WHERE MATCHES(text, 'ab&b')> 0;

TEXT
--------------------
AB&B

SQL>
```

This does not work

```
SQL> SELECT *  FROM    test_lexer_special WHERE MATCHES(text, 'at&t')> 0;

no rows selected

SQL> select token_text,token_extra from DR$test_ctxrule_index1$I;

TOKEN_TEXT           TOKEN_EXTRA
-------------------- --------------------
AB                   {B}

SQL>
```

Thanks.

Comment: any update on this ?